Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot (22.04 to 24.04)
sudo do-release-upgrade fails with:
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 621 M free 
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 152 M of 
disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt 
autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in 
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your 
initramfs. 

Restoring original system state

Aborting

now my problem is that my /boot partition (installed and sized and formatted by kubuntu 22.04 installer) is only 704MB:
/dev/nvme0n1p2              704M  205M  448M  32% /boot

and my only installed kernel takes about 200MB:
$ ls -lah /boot
total 197M
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K aug   30 16:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K juuni 16  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K juuli 30 17:33 config-6.8.0-40-generic
drwx------  4 root root 4.0K jaan   1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K aug   30 16:38 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 aug   30 13:38 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 173M aug   30 13:38 initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 aug   30 16:38 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
drwx------  2 root root  16K märts  2  2021 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K veebr  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K veebr  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K veebr  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 8.3M juuli 30 17:33 System.map-6.8.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 aug   30 13:38 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M juuli 30 18:17 vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 aug   30 16:38 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic

So there is nothing anymore I can remove from there... and it still wants me to free up additional 152MB?

Is there anything I can do to increase the /boot size somehow?

nvme0n1                259:5    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1            259:6    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2            259:7    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3            259:8    0 237.3G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt    252:0    0 237.2G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgkubuntu-root   252:1    0 236.3G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgkubuntu-swap_1 252:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]

I don't know... maybe nuke the vgkubuntu-swap_1 somehow and add the freed space from nvme0n1p3 to nvme0n1p2? But I really don't know how.

Or is there anything I can do to reduce the 621MB do-release-upgrade asks for somehow?

Or is there some easy way to move /boot partition somewhere else (temporarily) if I were to add another disk or USB stick to system? Do the upgrade and move "boot" back (if it doesn't actually require this absurd amount of space after install)?



My upgrade from 22.04.4 to 24.04.1 needed 2.2 gig Suggest that 152 meg more may still be short.

Try deleting the memtest files.

kyodake, memtest files collectively take less than 1MB, so wouldn't help much.

Your main objective is to upgrade from Kubuntu 22.04 to Kubuntu 24.04, yet you don't have enough space in your /boot directory. There are a few ways to go about this:

Save your data, install Kubuntu 24.04, & restore your data
This will certainly be the easiest and least risky option.

Create new initrd images with a different compression setting and limit the modules included.
This may not work, but it just might reduce the size of your current initrd image enough to allow you to proceed with upgrading.

Create a new & larger /boot partition and move the contents of your current /boot into the new /boot
This is doable, but you would need to have free space on your current drive, which you currently don't have. However, you could try to shrink your root partition to gain more free space on the drive, but this would be another task in itself.

Move the contents of your current /boot, which is in a separate partition, into the /boot directory of your root partition.
This is not something you can do, because you have a LUKS encrypted drive.

Add another hard disk or USB flash drive and move the contents of your current /boot into the new /boot.
This has a high chance of success, but is somewhat difficult and risky. However, there's an added benefit of not having to boot into a Live CD or enter a chroot environment.


I'll outline both Options 2 and 5 below.

Warning: There is a risk of damaging your system if you make any mistakes where you won't be able to boot. In this case, you'd most likely be booted to the Grub Rescue prompt, which would entail a different set of instructions to remedy. Therefore, backup all your data before proceeding. Worst case scenario, you can install Kubuntu 24.04 and restore your data that you just backed up. ;)

Option 2
Change initramfs.conf COMPRESS and MODULES settings
By changing the compression algorithm and the Modules settings, this will shrink the initrd images, because it only contains the modules needed to mount the root partition. The risk is that the system will no longer boot if there are system configuration changes. So proceed with caution.

First, check the current size of your initrd image:
$ ls -lh /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  128M Sep 1 22:06 initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic


Next, edit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf:
sudo nano /etc/initrams-tools/initramfs.conf
Change the following lines from this:
MODULES=most
COMPRESS=zstd

...to this:
MODULES=dep
COMPRESS=xz

You may want to try lzma compression instead of xz to see if the size is even smaller.

After making these changes, rebuild your initrd image:
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all

Then check the size again:
$ ls -lh /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Sep 1 22:24 initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic



As you can see, my initrd image was reduced from 128M to 39M. Considering your image is 173M, it may be possible, but no guarantee.
If this gives you enough space to upgrade, you can always revert these changes after the upgrade and create new initrd images.
Option 5
Move /boot directory to new hard drive

Open your Konsole terminal

Partition your new drive

Assuming you've installed a USB thumb drive and it shows up as /dev/sda, run:
sudo parted /dev/sda

Create a label
mklabel gpt

Make partition
mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%

Display partition table
print

Exit parted
quit



Format your new drive
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1

Mount new hard drive, /dev/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

Copy current /boot directory to new hard drive
sudo cp -a /boot/* /mnt/

Unmount new hard drive, /dev/sda1
sudo umount /dev/sda1

Unmount current /boot/efi and /boot directories
sudo umount /boot/efi
sudo umount /boot


Mount new hard drive, /dev/sda1, to /boot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot

Mount efi partition
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi

Update /etc/fstab

Get UUID of new hard drive, /dev/sda1
sudo blkid

Copy UUID of /dev/sda1 into /etc/fstab. Replace this UUID for the current one associated with /dev/nvme0n1p2. If you want, you can comment the line with the original UUID using a # and then copy/paste the line below using the new UUID. Something like the following:
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
#UUID=4e2995ca-c733-414a-8d2d-e2ccd992f12c /boot               ext4    defaults 0       2
UUID=0d092f19-c04a-439e-8fa2-3e82cd29787d /boot               ext4    defaults 0       2




Re-install Grub.
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Note: Although the /boot directory is technically on a different hard drive, we are still re-installing Grub to your main hard drive where your root filesystem is. Since /dev/sda is mounted to /boot and /dev/nvme0n1p1 is mounted to /boot/efi, there is no need to add options such as --boot-directory= and --efi-directory=.

Update initramfs
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all

Update Grub config
sudo update-grub

Reboot computer
sudo reboot



After this, you can proceed with your upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04. If successful, you can revert your /boot directory to /dev/nvme0n1p2 using the steps above in reverse or delete the old /dev/nvme0n1p2 partition as follows:

Run parted:
sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1

Display current partition table:
print

Delete partition for old /boot, nvme0n1p2, (adjust accordingly):
rm 2

If you display partition table again, you'll see that it's removed:
print

Exit parted:
quit


Good luck.


Can you really "boot" from LUKS encrypted partition (if you move your "/boot" to LUKS encrypted main drive)? 2. Can you do this procedure from within working Kubuntu, if you don't have access to Live DVD (bios locked, can't change boot order)


@deemon I overlooked that it was encrypted. I've updated my answer with two different options.

Thank you very much! Option 5 worked like a charm. However in hindsight I should have sudo vim do-release-upgrade and reduced the /boot partition free space requirement from 621MB to 200MB and it would have been just fine! During the upgrade in no point did the free space on the new bigger boot went down more than 100MB. Why ubuntu wants you to have 621MB exactly free is anyone's guess - most probably "just in case".

eexcept, that instead of points 1-3 I used "KDE Partition manager" instead; skipped 8-9 and after doing point 10 used sudo mount -a (to both mount the new partition and to test fstab correct working order) and then just in case also sudo ls -la /boot and sudo ls -la /boot/efi to be extra sure, the partitions were there with files also. But everything else was exactly like you asked me to.

@deemon That’ll work. Glad you got it figured out

also in option 5 point 5 there was this issue, that cp -a /boot/* /mnt/ copied over entire /boot/efi partition content also, but needed was only empty folder for mount point. So I had to delete the content from there (which was 2 folders in my case, EFI and 'System Volume Information') sudo rm -R /mnt/efi/EFI and sudo rm -R /mnt/efi/'System Volume Information'
